# How to move to other viewcontrollers by using button and textfield?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

How to move to other viewcontrollers by using button and textfield?

I've got over 100 viewcontrollers.

For example

If a user put 10 in the textfield and click the button next to it, he can move to the viewcontroller with storyboard ID '10'

Or if the user put 77 in thr textfield, he can move to the viewcontroller with storyboard ID 77.

Or similar like this...

Thank you.

Comment: In the action associated with the button, you should be able to instantiate a ViewController based off of the value inside of the text field. In other words, you could do something like : 
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: textfield.text)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this doing something like:

```
   @IBAction func textFieldButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: textfield.text!)
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
```

**Summary**

As long as the ID for the ViewControllers matches whatever is being typed in the textfield, that should do the trick. You might want to add additional code to verify whatever is being entered.